# Forming a tree with this format in DrRacket (or Scheme)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, binary-tree, racket

So I am using DrRacket and have a struct defined as:

```
(define-struct thing (a b))
```

Then, I have an example tree of this format:

```
(define v (make-thing 
              (make-thing (make-thing 1 2) 
                          (make-thing 3 4))  
              (make-thing (make-thing 5 6) 
                          (make-thing 7 8))))
```

I need to build a function which takes in a non-positive number which is also a power of 2 (so like 1,2,4,8,16...) and either outputs the number 1 (if n=1) or makes a 'thing' in the format as above.

So far I have tried a lot of ways but I either end up getting something like:

```
(make-thing (make-thing (make-thing 1 1) 
                        (make-thing 1 1)) 
            (make-thing (make-thing 1 1) 
                        (make-thing 1 1))))
```

I cannot figure out how to increment the variables properly - I've been able to figure out how to apply the required number of `make-thing`s:

Here's the code I use right now:

```
(define (helper pow current)
  (cond
    ((= pow 0) 1)
    (else (make-thing 
             (helper (- pow 1) current) 
             (helper (- pow 1) (- current 1))))))

(define current 1)

(define (build-thing-or-number n)
  (cond
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (else (make-thing 
             (helper (- (log n 2) 1) current) 
             (helper (- (log n 2) 1) (add1 current))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to call your `build-thing-or-number` just `g`, so I have less typing to do.

So you want

```lisp
(g 1)   =   1                  ; you've got this covered already
(g 2)   =   (thing 1 2)
(g 4)   =   (thing (thing 1 2) (thing 3 4))
(g 8)   =   (thing (thing (thing 1 2) (thing 3 4))       ; 1..4
                   (thing (thing 5 6) (thing 7 8)))      ; 5..8
```

We see that if we had more parameters it'd be much easier to do:

```lisp
(define (h a b)                        ; from ... to
  (cond 
     ((= (+ a 1) b)                    ; like (h 1 2):
        (make-thing a b))              ;    just make the thing
     (else                             ; e.g. (h 1 4)   (h 5 8)
        (let ([c (/ (+ a b -1) 2)])    ;       c = 2     c = 6 
          (make-thing                  ; c is the middle
                 (h a c)               ; make the first half   1..2   1..4
                 (h ..... ))))))       ; and the second        3..4   5..8
```

And we use it simply as

```lisp
(define (g b)
  (cond ((= b 1) 1)
        (else (h ..... ))))
```

And that's that!

Answer (score 2):

```
#lang racket

(define-struct thing (a b) #:transparent)
```

I've defined thing as transparent, for ease of verification

```
(define (helper level max)
  (if (equal? (/ level 2) 1)
      (make-thing (- max 1) max)
      (make-thing (helper (/ level 2) (- max (/ level 2))) (helper (/ level 2) max))))
```

max is equal to the highest number in the current thing
level is the highest number in the simplest (read lowest values) thing of the same shape (i.e. (thing (thing 5 6) (thing 7 8)) has a max of 8 and a level of 4)

```
(define (build-thing-or-number n)
  (cond
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (else (helper n n))))
```

as you can see, helper does all the work.

Comment: nice touch with the transparent.